# Variable g may not have been initialized

Tags: java, initialization, try-catch

I have many questions about this project that I'm working on. It's a virtual database for films. I have a small MovieEntry class (to process individual entries) and a large MovieDatabase class that keeps track of all 10k+ entries. In my second searchYear method as well as subsequent methods I get the error "variable g (or d or whatever) might not have been initialized." 
I also get a pop-up error that says `Warnings from last compilation: unreachable catch clause. thrown type java.io.FileNotFoundException has already been caught.` I'm positively stumped on both. Here's the code:

```
public class MovieDatabase
{
   private ArrayList<MovieEntry> Database = new ArrayList<MovieEntry>();
   public MovieDatabase(){
       ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);
    }

   public int countTitles() throws IOException{
       Scanner fileScan;
       fileScan = new Scanner (new File("movies.txt"));
       int count = 0;
       String movieCount;
       while(fileScan.hasNext()){
           movieCount = fileScan.nextLine();
           count++;
        }
       return count;
    }

   public void addMovie(MovieEntry m){
       Database.add(m);
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchTitle(String substring){
       for (MovieEntry title : Database)
          System.out.println(title);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchGenre(String substring){
       for (MovieEntry genre : Database)
          System.out.println(genre);
          return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchDirector (String str){
       for (MovieEntry director : Database)
          System.out.println(director);
       return null;
    }

   public ArrayList<String> searchYear (int yr){
       ArrayList <String> yearMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (MovieEntry m : Database)
          m.getYear(yr);
       if(yearMatches.contains(yr) == false){
           String sYr = Integer.toString(yr);
           yearMatches.add(sYr);
        }
       return yearMatches;
    }

   public ArrayList<MovieEntry> searchYear(int from, int to){
       ArrayList <String> Matches = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(MovieEntry m : Database);
          m.getYear();
          Matches.add();
       return Matches;
    }

   public void readMovieData(String movies){
       String info;
       try{
           Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File("movies"));
           Scanner lineReader;

           while(fileReader.hasNext()){
               info = fileReader.nextLine();

               lineReader = new Scanner(info);
               lineReader.useDelimiter(":");

               String title = lineReader.next();
               String director = lineReader.next();
               String genre = lineReader.next();
               int year = lineReader.nextInt();
            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException error){
            System.out.println("File not found.");

        }catch(IOException error){
            System.out.println("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        }
    }

   public int countGenres(){
    ArrayList <String> gList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(MovieEntry m : Database){
      String g = m.getGenre(g);
      if(gList.contains(g) == false){
        gList.add(g);
      }
      return gList.size();
    }
    }

    public int countDirectors(){
     ArrayList <String> dList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(MovieEntry m : Database){
        String d = m.getDirector(d);
        if(dList.contains(d) == false){
            dList.add(d);
        }
        return dList.size();
     }

     }

    public String listGenres(){
        ArrayList <String> genreList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }




}
```

Comment: can you please tell us if its `g` or `d`, so we know what part of the code to look at ?

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific than 'variable g (or d or whatever)'. Lines help. Specific variable names help more.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(IOException error){
            System.out.println("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        }
```

Its telling you that the `FileNotFoundException` will deal with what the IOException is catching, so the IOException becomes unreachable as in it will never catch an IO exceltion, why just not catch an [Exception](http://www.akadia.com/services/java_exceptions.html) instead

As for the initialization

```
public int countDirectors(){
     ArrayList <String> dList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(MovieEntry m : Database){
        String d = m.getDirector(d);  //THIS LINE
        if(dList.contains(d) == false){
            dList.add(d);
        }
        return dList.size();
     }
```

The line `String d = m.getDirector(d);` might be the problem, `d` wont be initialised unless there is something in the MovieEntry and as far as i can see there will never be anything because you are initialising it to an empty array list

`ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);`

Maybe you should be passing a array of movies to the constructor and then add these movies to the `Database` variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are a number of issues with this code.

What parameter does MovieEntry.getGenre() expect?  You may not use g in that case because it has not been defined yet.

The exception issue you mentioned means that the exception was already caught, or possibly never thrown.  I believe that in this case the IOException is never thrown out from the code within the try block.

There are a number of methods that are supposed to return a value but do not, example:

```
public String listGenres(){
    ArrayList <String> genreList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Also, it is a java naming convention to use lower case first characters (camel case) for values:

```
private ArrayList<MovieEntry> database = new ArrayList<MovieEntry>();
```

Oh, and do you need to re-initialize the database variable in the constructor?:

```
public MovieDatabase(){
   ArrayList<MovieDatabase> Database = new ArrayList<MovieDatabase>(0);
}
```

Hope this is helpful.